# How can i switch this code to be displayed on a carousel pro flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to display those images into a carousel pro but with no luck.
There are some photos from firestore storage that I want to display in my mobile app, and its working, but I just want to be in a carousel slide.

```
class ImagesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget makeImagesGrid() {
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount: 7,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ImageGridItem(index+1);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test Image"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: makeImagesGrid(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageGridItem extends StatefulWidget {

  int _index;

  ImageGridItem(int index){
    this._index = index;
  }
  @override
  _ImageGridItemState createState() => _ImageGridItemState();
}

class _ImageGridItemState extends State<ImageGridItem> {
  
  Uint8List imageFile;
  StorageReference photosReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images/reklama");
  
  getImage() {
    int MAX_SIZE = 7*1024*1024;
    
    photosReference.child("reklama_${widget._index}.jpg").getData(MAX_SIZE).then((data) {
      this.setState(() {
        imageFile = data;
      });
    }).catchError((error){
      debugPrint(error.toString());
    });
  }
  
  Widget decideGridTileWidget() {
    if(imageFile == null) {
      return Center(child: Image.asset("images/reklama.jpg"));
    }else {
      return Image.memory(imageFile,fit: BoxFit.cover);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getImage();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridTile(child: decideGridTileWidget());
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a tool such as Grammarly to improve your writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) and [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) should help you to do what you want, you don't really need to handle the image from firestore and the carousel sliding widget yourself. Example of using cached_network_image to show image from firestore is as below:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: FirebaseStorage.instance
         .ref()
         .child('images/kartelaime.jpg')  // Your image path in firestore
         .getDownloadURL(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.data != null)
        return CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: snapshot.data);
      else return Container();  
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please If it is possible a code example

i am trying something like that but the images on here to be from firebase storage and like in first example not each image to give a path but all images on that folder

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget imageCarousel = new Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: new Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        images: [
          AssetImage('images/kartelaime.jpg'),
          AssetImage('images/shperblime.png'),
          AssetImage('images/7vitemeridian.png'),
          AssetImage('images/ndertshpis.jpg'),
          AssetImage('images/ofertatjavore.png'),
          AssetImage('images/zgjerimi.jpeg'),
        ],
        autoplay: false,
        animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
        dotSize: 4.0,
        indicatorBgPadding: 4.0,
        dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
```